# Distance between points (x0, y0) and (x1, y1)

Tags: java, distance, points, between

I am new to programming and looking for help into finding the distance between points

What I currently have is this:

```
import java.util.*;

class WS8Q2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    double x0=0;
    double x1=0;
    double y0=0;
    double y1=0;

    System.out.println("Please enter 4 numbers");
    x0=in.nextDouble();

    double distance = (x0, y1, x1, y0);
    System.out.print(answer);
    }


    public static double distance (x0, y1, x1,y0) {
        return Math.Sqrt ((x1 - y0) * (y1-y0) + (x1-x0) * (x1-x0));
    }
```

I am really unsure of how to do it, as I have never done distances before, and I am just completely lost, have tried to look up certain formulas but the only thing I found that seemed as some what useful to me is in this website [link](http://langref.org/all-languages/numbers/mathematical/distance-between-points) Which doesn't seem to say much to me

EDIT: Here is the question and what I am trying to achieve by the way:

> Design a function distance that takes four fractional number parameters x0,  y0, x1, and y1, and returns the distance between points (x0, y0) and (x1, y1). (Look up the formula if you can’t remember it!)

Comment: I am confused by your ordering of your x and y variables.  wouldn't the order be x0/y0 and x1/y1?  You seem to have x0/y1 and x1/y0.

Comment: @CodeChimp That's basically what the question is about.

Comment: Your exact problem is not related to Java programming but understanding the formula of the distance between two points that you can seek on the net. Here's a good explanation: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to print `distance` not `answer`. Second, it gave you the [answer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot%28double,%20double%29) on your link.... try this

```
public static double distance (double x0, double y1, double x1, double y0) {
  return Math.hypot(x1-x0, y1-y0); // <-- From your link.
}
```

The formula for finding the distance between two points is precisely the same as the Pythagorean Theorem, find the length of the hypotenuse. That is c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>.

Finally, you need to read in all four doublle(s)... not just one.

```
x0=in.nextDouble(); // Good.            1
x1=in.nextDouble(); // And another...   2
y0=in.nextDouble(); // And another...   3
y1=in.nextDouble(); // One more.        4
```

Comment: ah, thanks everyone for your answer, i can see that i am on the right track with this now, the only part that I didn't really understand is the error that I keep getting in this part: "java:25: <identifier> expected
        public static double distance (x0, y1, x1, y0) {"

what does it mean by <identifier> expected?

Comment: @user3062391 Edited, you were missing the types for the arguments.

Comment: ah thank you so much, it's these little problems that i always have trouble with, although i had the correct formula i didn't know i had to write (double x0...etc) well at least i learnt something new today, thank you very much !

Answer (score 10):

The distance equation for two point`(x0, y0)` and `(x1, y1)` should be:

```
Math.Sqrt ((x1 - x0) * (x1-x0) + (y1-y0) * (y1-Y0));
```

consider approaching as OOP: declare a class Point with (x ,Y) attribute, declare a `setLocation(a, b)` function and declare `getDistance(Point)` function:

```
class Point
{
   double x;
   double y;

   Point(double x, double y)
   {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
  }

  public double getDistance(Point p)
  {
    // now implement it
  } 
}
```

In Addition, if you are not already aware of java has a [Point2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance%28double,%20double%29) class which has a [`distance(double px, double py)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance%28double,%20double%29) function.

Comment: By the way, even if you do this minor change, OP's code won't compile since he/she uses an `answer` undefined variable in `main` method.

Comment: OP's code has more than one error: i just gave a formula and then a suggestion so he could approach to solve the problem now. Thank you :)

Comment: In fact, even OP posts the (wrong) formula, but that's only part of the problem. I suggest to re read the question (which, in the end, is like *can you do the homework for me please*).

Comment: i didn't mean it like that, even with the link that i supplied, i didn't really understand where and how to properly implement it, everything that i tried out was always incorrect

but it seems that i am on the right track now!

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the distance using this function...

```
public static double distance (x0, y1, x1,y0) {
    return Math.Sqrt (Math.pow((y1 - y0),2) + Math.pow((x1-x0),2));
}
```

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza. Thank you for the correction